# $PATH using NVM and installing NPM

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I have installed NVM, and now I am trying to install NPM so I can import my packages for my nodejs application. I run a digitalocean vps.

If I type

> "node -v"

I get the `0.10.19` version that is installed in my nvm folder. The folder is ~/.nvm/v0.10.19/bin. Typing "node -v" confirms that I have my $PATh works properly.

When I run the  sh install.sh script to install NPM, I get the following error:

> npm cannot be installed without nodejs. Install node first, and then
>   try again.
>
> Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH? Note that running as
>   sudo can change envs.
>
> PATH=~/.nvm/v0.10.19/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

I'm really confused, since the path to the node executable is actually printed out in the console when the sh fails...

Comment: Can you run "bash -x install.sh" to see how it tries to detect nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodejs version 0.10.19 should come with npm with it. 
Pleas issue the below command

```
npm -v
```

I have nodejs version 0.10.15 and it installed npm for me.

Answer (score 4):

Do not run npm commands with sudo. nvm is installed in your home directory in part because it is intended to be used as a normal user not root.